# MSSQL Concatenate three columns and then use WHERE

Tags: sql-server

I am using MSSQL server.  What I am trying to do is concatenate 3 columns from the same table into one result so I can then use the WHERE clause on the results.

This is the command I would like to run:

`select col1 + col2 + col3 as result from table where result like '%term%'`

However I keep getting hit with `Invalid column name 'result'`

I have seen lots of answers about concatenating columns, but none seem to use the WHERE clause on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This

```
SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 AS result
FROM TABLE
WHERE col1 LIKE '%term%'
    OR col2 LIKE '%term%'
    OR col3 LIKE '%term%'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT col1 + col2 + col3 AS result
    FROM TABLE
    ) t
WHERE result LIKE '%term%'
```

Comment: Yes thank you, the second option was perfect.  What is the t for at the end of the inner query brackets?

Comment: Thats the alias name for the sub query. Find more in here   https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Search VARCHAR(10)='term' 
SELECT Concat(col1, col2, col3) AS result 
FROM   table 
WHERE  Charindex(@Search, Concat(col1, col2, col3)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inner table to return result and search on returned column.

```
    SELECT * FROM 
(select col1 + col2 + col3 as result from [table] ) a 
where result like '%term%'
```

Comment: Here a after () block means table alias. We are selecting from table created by block within () and referenced that using a.